# Tension forces horizontal equal to $mg$? centripetal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, centripetal-force

[image]

Is the total tension of the system shown equal to Mg? If it is, why? I thought the horizontal forces have no effect on vertical forces.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659046/2451

Answer (score 0):

As this resembles a homework like question I shouldn't give a complete answer. But a good thing to remember is that if you do not consider the mass of the string itself or frictions on it, then whether horizontal or vertical, the tension is the same at all points of the string.