# Pulling a mass moving in a circle inwards

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

[image: 1]

In this question, I couldn't derive the right answer if I equate
$$\text{tension} = \text{radial acceleration} = \frac{v^2}{r}$$

Why shouldn't I equate that?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659046/305718

Comment: You can't equate a force to an acceleration.

Comment: Your acceleration is for circular motion.  This motion is spiral.

Comment: @ACB sorry. Actually meant to equate Tension = ma = radial acceleration

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the exercise is badly written. Let's have a set up like this. The ball is circulating at radius $r_0$ with speed $v_0$. At that moment you are right, the centripetal acceleration is $v_0^2/r_0$.

However if we pull the string that the radius is $r$ because the forces are central angular momentum is conserved and the new speed now becomes $v=v_0\cdot r_0/r$. This results in centripetal acceleration being $a_c=(v_0r_0)^2/r^3$ therefore force is proportional to $r^{-3}$.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your answer using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future posts, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thank a lot. Love from INDIA ❤️